# How to run two node.js commands independently in windows?

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

In windows, I run 2 commands like this

```
node watcher.js && node server.js
```

The first runs a watcher script, and the second runs a server. The problem is both are persistent and don't actually end. So the running server part never happens because the watcher script still runs.

Is there a way I can say to run both but don't care about finishing a script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
start node watcher.js && start node server.js
```

this will start two cmd programs independently.